# Get DocuSign Connect Webhook message on .NET Core API POST action method

Tags: c#, docusignapi, docusignconnect

I have integrated DocuSign connect (REST v2.1) with my .NET Core 5 project. But I am not sure how to get the notification body once the Webhook sends its request to the POST URL I have configured.

Comment: You can read the request body

Comment: @Chetan: I have tried already but it is empty.

Comment: How the DocuSign is going to use the webhook? What data it is supposed to send in the webhook. Can you share the code which reads the request body? Did you check if the request had any query string parameters?

Comment: @Chetan: I have tried something like this: 
if (!Request.Body.CanSeek)
            {
                Request.EnableBuffering();
            }

            Request.Body.Position = 0;

            var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8);

            var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue using the below code.

```
if (!Request.Body.CanSeek) { Request.EnableBuffering(); } 
Request.Body.Position = 0; 
var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8); 
var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```